# Operation error 2019 after deploying app

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I've managed to deploy my app however, i'm completely stuck after getting this error after opening up the app. I have been investigating and I keep thinking i've installed the wrong version of mysqldb?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~coherent-galaxy-xxxxx/1.383270042073427138/servicecatalog.py", line 23, in get
    db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + _INSTANCE_NAME, host='xxxxxx', port=3306, db='xxxxxx', user='root', charset='utf 8')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.set_character_set(charset)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 301, in set_character_set
    super(Connection, self).set_character_set(charset)
OperationalError: (2019, "Can't initialize character set utf 8 (path: /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/)")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `utf 8` (with a space) is not valid - See [MySQLdb can't initialize character set utf-8 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709659/mysqldb-cant-initialize-character-set-utf-8-error), which is a better explination of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have charset='utf 8' included in your MySQLdb.connect line of code. Remove it and you should be fine.