# MySQLdb can't initialize character set utf-8 error

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am trying to insert some Arabic word into the `arabic_word` column of my `hanswehr2` database Maria DB using the MySQLdb driver.

I was getting a `latin-1 encode error`. But after reading around, I found out that the MySQLdb driver was defaulted to `latin-1` and I had to explicitly set `utf-8` as my charset of choice at the `mariadb.connect()` function. [Sauce.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874947/6388893)

The entire database is set to utf-8.

**Code:**

```
def insert_into_db(arabic_word, definition):
    try:
        conn = mariadb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'xyz1234passwd', 'hans_wehr', charset='utf-8', use_unicode=True)
        conn.autocommit(True)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO hanswehr2 (arabic_word , definition) VALUES (%s,%s)", (arabic_word, definition,))
    except mariadb.Error, e:
        print e
        sys.exit(1)
```

However now I get the following **error**:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/heisenberg/hans_wehr/main.py
Total lines 87672
(2019, "Can't initialize character set utf-8 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have specified the Python MySQL driver to use the utf-8 character however it seems to ignore this.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is it a possible duplicate? The question you referenced is in PHP

Comment: oopps, sorry about that. But you should really try to call `'utf8` seems that can help. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203782/4421474

Comment: `utf-8` (with a hyphen) is not a valid character set name. Use `utf8`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Could you write your `utf8` comment as an answer inorder to help future SO users. Thank you.

Comment: @KenOkech Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The charset alias for UTF-8 in MySQL is **`utf8`** (no hyphen).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html for available charsets.

Note, if you need to use non-BMP Unicode points, such as emojis, use `utf8mb4` for the connection charset and the varchar type.

Answer (score -1):

There is a thing called **collations** that helps encode/decode characters for specific languages.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95048/what-is-the-difference-between-collation-and-character-set

I think u need to **specify** it when **creating** your **database** **table** **or** in the **connection string**. refer this:
[store arabic in SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560173/store-arabic-in-sql-database)

More on **python mysql connection** :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-set-charset-collation.html